Fourier transform of analytic semigroups
I'm reading Analysis in Banach Spaces III - Hytönen, van Neervan, Veraar, Weis and have a doubt in the following proof:


More precisely, I don't get how the second last equality, namely (ii), is obtained.

I definitely don't think it's using the definition of the generator but rather the Laplace transform representation of the resolvent (LTRR):
$$
\begin{align*}
A(1+A)^{-1} \hat{k_{\delta}}(\phi) 
& = \int_{\mathbb R} A(1+A)^{-1} \hat{k_{\delta}}(\xi)\phi(\xi) \ d\xi\\
& = \int_{\mathbb R} A(1+A)^{-1} \left(\int_0^\infty e^{-2\pi i\xi t} e^{-\delta t}S(t)\phi(\xi)\ dt\right)  \ d\xi\qquad \text{(Definition of Fourier transform)} \\
& =  \int_{\mathbb R} A(1+A)^{-1} (2\pi i\xi+\delta+A)^{-1}\phi(\xi) \ d\xi \qquad \text{(LTRR)}.
\end{align*}
$$

Is this right? If yes, can someone explain how I can justify the first equality?


I think you are right, you have to use Laplace's formula. What further justification do you seek for the first equality?

@EvangelopoulosFoivos Yes, I think Laplace's formula needs to be used somewhere but I can't figure out the exact details.

To justify (ii):
$\forall \delta \in (0, \infty)$ and $\phi \in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R};X)$:
$$
\begin{align*}
 \hat{k_{\delta}}(\phi) 
& = \int_{\mathbb R}  k_{\delta}(\xi) \hat{\phi}(\xi) \ d\xi \quad \text{def. of distributional F.T.}\\
& = \int_{\mathbb R}  k_{\delta}(\xi) \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-2\pi i\xi t} \phi(t)\ dt \ d\xi  \quad \text{def. of F.T.} \\
&= \int_\mathbb{R}\int_{\mathbb R}  k_{\delta}(\xi) e^{-2\pi i\xi t} \phi (t) \ d \xi \ dt \quad \text{Fubini}  \\
& =  \int_{\mathbb R} \int_0^\infty e^{- (\delta + 2 \pi i t) \xi }   S(\xi)  \phi (t)  \ d \xi \ d t \quad \text{def. of} \ k_\delta \\
&= \int_{\mathbb R} (\delta + 2\pi i t + A)^{-1} \phi (t) \ d t \quad \text{L.T. of } S \text{ is resolvent of} \ -A
\end{align*}
$$

But the remark above the proof in the books says that $A(1+A)^{-1}$? can't be left out?

The remark says that they cant be left out of the original statement, but here i think they can be left out. They can only not be left out when letting $\delta \to 0$.

The second equality in the original proof also contains the term $\int k_{\delta}(\xi) \hat{\phi}(\xi)\ d\xi$. What's the point of applying definition of distributional F.T. twice, then?

@modeltheory How should i know? i am not the author.
